# Trouble understanding setuid/setgid

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I've been trying to wrap my head around how setuid/setgid work... I came up with this contrived example:

Users:

userA belongs to group A

userB belongs to group B

File a.txt is owned by userA with permissions `rw-rw----` (660). I thought if userA created this file, test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat a.txt
```

and ran either `chmod g+s test.sh` or `chmod u+s test.sh` that upon execution by userB, it would cat a.txt.  Instead, I get `Permission Denied`.  Just to be clear, the file permissions for test.sh end up looking like this: `rwsr-xr-x` or `rwxr-sr-x`.  I thought the whole point of setuid/setgid was that when other users executed the file, they would assume the user id or group id of the file (test.sh in this case).  Am I doing something wrong, or is my understanding off?

I've been running my test on RedHat in case that matters.  I've also tried playing with `umask`, attempting to run the setuid/setgid after running `umask 0002`.  Didn't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WARNING: Setuid and setgid shell scripts are a security hole.  There are lots of ways for someone to cause a setuid/setgid to do things that you (the author) didn't intend.

A common trick is to monkey with the environment variables.  For example, someone could do this:

```
ln -s cat /bin/rm
export PATH=.:${PATH}
```

then use your setuid script to **delete** the `a.txt` file.

---

Fortunately, the setuid and setgid bits are **ignored** for shell scripts on many modern Linux systems; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts.  Some of the answers give workarounds ...